# IoC solution to non-referential dependency

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, ninject

Right now I have a type structure similar to the following

```
interface IFoo { }
class FooA : IFoo { }
class FooB : IFoo { }

//not a builder. generates based on conditions
interface IFooEmitter<TFoo> 
{
    TFoo EmitFoo(); 
} 

abstract class FooEmitterBase<TFoo> : IFooEmitter<TFoo> { }

class FooAEmitter : FooEmitterBase<FooA> { }

[RequiresEmitter(typeof(FooAEmitter))]
class FooBEmitter : FooEmitterBase<FooB> { }
```

I want to create a FooBEmitter somewhere...

```
var b = FooEmitterManager.CreateAndStore<FooBEmitter>();
```

Create() sees the RequiresEmitter attribute on FooBEmitter and recursively creates a FooAEmitter.

```
//continued from above
var a = FooEmitterManager.CreateAndStore<FooAEmitter>();
Debug.Assert(a == b); // true
```

**FooBEmitter does NOT classically depend on (store a reference to) FooAEmitter.** It depends on

- FooAEmitter being constructed and stored in FooEmitterManager
- The FooA's that FooAEmitter will generate

Is there some way to simplify this type of dependency aware creation using popular .NET IoC containers like Castle or NInject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably what you are looking for for Ninject: https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.dependencycreation